# Why was Jor-El played by two different people?

Tags: smallville

When Clark talks to 'his father' in the fortress of Solitude Terence Stamp provided the voice, but when Jor-El himself (at least in season 9) physically appeared he was portrayed by Julian Sands- was this casting decision ever explained?

Comment: This probably belongs on the Movies and TV stack; its an entirely out-of-universe question.

Comment: it is definitely on-topic here. It's a behind-the-scenes question related to a work of science fiction.

Comment: [Relevant meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6594/5184) and [more here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2944/5184)

Comment: Equally [relevant meta-meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259182/difference-between-movies-tv-and-scifi-and-fantasy-stack-exchanges/259184#259184)

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**: Terrence Stamp is "older and wiser" Jor-El, and Julian Sands is "younger" Jor-El.

---

As I understand it, Julian Sands was meant to be playing a "younger version" of Jor-El; one that was the same age as the other trapped Kandorians. By the time of Smallville's season 9, Terrence Stamp would have been a bit to old to play someone of that age.

Note that, in the Season 3 episode "Memoria", in a flashback to Krypton, Terrence Stamp *is* playing Jor-El, right before the planet explodes. Additionally, Tom Welling himself played Jor-El in an even-younger-version that was on Earth in the 60s. So Jor-El's appearance has changed pretty dramatically over the timeline of the show.